# JSX: when are JavaScript expressions evaluated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby

After going through GatsbyJS and React tutorials I got the impression that JavaScript expressions are always evaluated when they are inside {} brackets in JSX. But now I'm looking at a JSX file inside a GatsbyJS starter repo, where it looks like the brackets cause different behavior:

```
const {
    data: {
      posts: { edges: posts },
      site: {
        siteMetadata: { facebook }
      }
    }
} = props;
```

([Source](https://github.com/greglobinski/gatsby-starter-hero-blog/blob/master/src/pages/category.js))

According to the tutorials, "facebook" should be evaluated as JavaScript and should return undefined, but that's not what's happening. Somehow we end up with a JavaScript object data.site.siteMetadata.facebook, which has some data. What's going on here? Why is "facebook" not evaluated as a JavaScript expression?

Comment: I think it is evaluated and assigned based on a value by [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit of code you copy actually has nothing to do with JSX (see below). It's ES6 [object destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), like @PrithvirajSahu commented on the question.

Say you have an object like this:

```
const obj = {
  a: 100, 
  b: { 
    value: 200,
  } 
};
```

You can get the inner values like so:

```
const { a } = obj; 
// same as const a = obj.a

const { b: c } = obj; 
// same as const c = obj.b

const { b: { value } } = obj; 
// same as const value = obj.b.value

const { b: { value: v } } = obj; 
// same as const v = obj.b.value

const { a, { b: { value } } } = obj; 
// same as 
// const a = obj.a; 
// const value = obj.b.value;
```

So back to your piece of code, it's equivalent to

```
const posts = props.data.posts.edges;
const facebook = props.data.site.siteMetadata.facebook;
```

As you have found out, the destructuring syntax is very neat at 1 or maybe 2 levels, but hard to read when there're more. Personally, I only use it at 1 level.

---

**Edit**: In the function in the source, only the lines starting with `<...` is JSX syntax.

```
const CategoryPage = props => {
  // code here is normal js
  const { ... } = props;

  // JSX start from inside this return function
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      { /* code between bracket in this section will be evaluate as 'normal JS' */ }
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Caveat: The code between bracket in JSX has to evaluate to a function. If we write something like this:

```
<div className="container">
  Hello
  {"Happy"}
  World
</div>
```

Babel will turn it into the following regular JS:

```
React.createElement(
  "div",
  { className: "container" },
  "Hello",
  "Happy",
  "World"
);
```

[Play with babel here](https://babeljs.io/repl/)

Whatever we put between bracket will be passed to [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) as a child of the `div` element; therefore only valid React element can be placed here:

- Null (render nothing)
- A string (will become a DOM text node)
- Another React element
- An expression/function that evaluates to, or returns any of the above

```
<div>
  { hasDate && <Date /> }
<div>
```

or

```
// somewhere in the code
const showDate = (hasDate) => {
  if (!hasDate) return null;
  return <Date />
}

// in the render function
return (
  <div>
    { showDate(hasDate) }
  <div>
)
```

We also can use bracket to pass value to a element's props:

```
<div 
  style={ { color: 'red' } }
  onClick={ (event) => {...} }>
  { hasDate && <Date /> }
<div>
```

Comment: You're right. Minor nitpick: you said the code has nothing to do with JSX. It does. It's in a JSX file and my question was why it's not evaluated as JavaScript despite the brackets.

Comment: Hey @AtteJuvonen, I've edited the answer above a bit to clarify. When a file is named `.jsx`, it's often to signify to your compiler that the content of the file will have JSX syntax — it doesn't mean that everything inside the file is JSX. In the function you shared, only the `<...>` part is JSX syntax. `{ }` is a way to escape from JSX so you can put in normal JS code. But anywhere else is normal JS. If you put this destructure code outside of `.jsx` and into a normal ES6 `.js` file, it will work.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. One more thing: It doesn't look like I'm able to put "normal JS" in there. For example, if I put in `"if (true) { console.log("hey") }"` it will complain about syntax error.

Comment: Hey @AtteJuvonen! My bad, it's actually not *normal js* per se -- Let me edit the answer a bit more. But in short, JSX will be compiled to `React.createElement()`, which means you can only pass in value or function; but not literal block of code. If you extract that code into a function, then call that function inside of jsx, it'll work